# What is the relation between dielectric constant and hydrating tendency?

Tags: hydrogen

What is the relation between dielectric constant and hydrating tendency?

Could someone also explain both terms?

Comment: Completely different things...

Answer (score 5):

What Mithoron commented is not actually true. They are related in a a few ways.
First of all, I'll tell you about dielectric constant. The way I learned it, a dielectric constant is the ratio of the capacitance of a capacitor filled with a certain material (Let's say $C$), to the capacitance of the exact same capacitor in a vacuum (Lets call this $C_0$). The dielectric constant is just $C$/$C_0$.
Hydration tendency is a little more complicated, but after researching it, it seems that it is the ability of a substance to make another substance more soluble.
Water has a very high dielectric constant. If you look at water, the O-H bonds are polarized because they have a high electronegativity difference. This means that water has strong interactions with the ions of salts, creating hydration shells around them (This basically means the salt particles won't be attracted to each other as much). Stronger dipoles of water result in a greater dielectric constant, and a higher hydration tendency. I must admit though, this is a strange question. If you don't mind, you could you explain why you need it?